# What Catholic churches are these?

Tags: europe, identify-this, religion, vatican-city

I am trying to identify the buildings in this picture.

The one on the top left is in Vatican City, and the rest are also Catholic related but I'm not sure where they are.

All the pictures are from a postcard.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are the [Four Papal Basilicas](http://www.italymagazine.com/featured-story/romes-four-papal-basilicas) in Rome:

- Top-left: [St Peter's Basilica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._Peter%27s_Basilica): [image]
- Top-right: [Basilica of Saint Paul Outside the Walls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_of_Saint_Paul_Outside_the_Walls) - most photos - eg. the one on Wikipedia - show the more detailed Western face, but the drawing above depicts the Northern face: [image]
- Bottom-left: [Archbasilica of St. John Lateran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archbasilica_of_St._John_Lateran): [image]
- Bottom-right: [Basilica of Saint Mary Major](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_di_Santa_Maria_Maggiore): [image]

Comment: Aaaah Rome. Doesn't get any better.

Comment: Thanks a lot Brendan. I must admit I did not expect to get an answer. The pictures are from the four corners of a marriage cert.      Basilica of Saint Paul Outside the Walls is the least accurately drawn. I guess some artistic license.

Comment: The thing with The Basilica of St Paul Outside the Walls is that most photos online are from a different side of the building - usually from the courtyard on the west side. But the drawing here is showing the North side - here's a Google Maps view of the same side- matches the drawing pretty well: https://goo.gl/maps/ujmP7wzfGHk - I've also updated the photo in the answer and added explanation.

Comment: I see you can give the 'best answer' tick to an answer. This answer cannot be improved on!, so it must get the tick. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The specific names have already been mentioned, but those are the four "major" basilicas of Rome.

Often devoted pilgrims will make it a point to visit all 4 on a trip to Rome. (This is especially true during a "holy year" in which each of those basilicas has a special door that is only open during those events.)